# Compute number of times instance variable is increased

Tags: java, object, constructor

I'm setting an instance variable to a unique value,

i.e`private int registrationCourse = 2015000;` in an `object class`.

I want to increase this course number by `1` each time it is called from a `main method` so it becomes `2015001`, `2015002`, etc.

I think to do this, I have to create a class variable and initialize it to `0`, simply because it is not bound to a class. (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

i.e `private static int numCourses = 0;`

Then I have to make a constructor, and initialize the other instance variables, and increment the registration number in the following fashion:

```
numCourses =  registrationCourse;
numCourses++;
```

However, I am super new to dealing with constructors, so I do not understand why I don't have to make a `while`loop to do this. My other question would be when I try to return the `registrationCourse` number, for both cases, it obviously only returns the last incremented value, and I want to return a different valued, increased by one for each `object`. Any explanations??

Answer (score 1):

Your static value will be shared accross all *instances* of the class instances. If you like to maintain the actual *number* that is applicable during the instance-construction, you would need to copy it to a non-static (instance-bound) variable.

For example:

```
class c{
   private int registrationCourse = 2015000;
   private int incrementalValue = 0;
   private static int nextIncrementalValue = 0;

  public c(){
     nextIncrementalValue +=1; //increase static, shared value.
     this.incrementalValue = nextIncrementalValue; // set CURRENT value for later reference.
  }
}
```

If you now would construct 3 instances of `c`, each of them would have the *same* value for `nextIncrementalValue` (= `3`) because they all share the same static variable, but any instance would have it's own `incrementalValue` (= `{1,2,3}`)

Comment: Thank-you! Let's say that though, instead of each instance having the values `incrementalValue (= {1,2,3})`, I wanted them to have `incrementalValue (= {2015000,2015001,2015002})`. I'm doing similar code: `registrationCourse = 2015000; numCourses++; this.registrationCourse = numCourses;` But it's just giving me back `1,2,3..`, and NOT the incremented registration numbers. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: @user180708 then, you need to `this.incrementalValue = registrationCourse + nextIncrementalValue` if you want to have the first instance with `2015000`, increment the static variable AFTER the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

For your question about constructors, you don't need a while loop because your application is only concerned of counting how many objects are created. And for each object, the constructor gets invoked, therefore you only need the increment code in the constructor. You would probably need your while loop in your main() code if you decide how many objects you need to instantiate:

```
int i = 0;
while(i<10) {
    Course course = new Course(); // assuming your class is named Course
}
```

This will increment the counter 10 times.

For your second question on returning the value per object created, you would need an "instance" variable for this. So create another non-static variable and save the numCourses value in it:

```
static int totalCourses = 2015000;
int courseNumber = 0;

public Course() {
    totalCourses++;
    courseNumber = totalCourses;
}
```

So, what happens here is that the totalCourses just keep on incrementing every new object that you have. then each course number is saved and different per object.

Hope this helps.